# How to display image located in drawable folder in full screen in viewpager app?

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, gallery

I have developed an app that is suppose to show the image to user using viewpager. But my problem is that my images are not showing in full screen . can any one please suggest the codes for how to make this work ?. Following are my codes..

Mainactivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ShareActionProvider;




public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    MediaPlayer oursong;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      oursong = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.a);
      oursong.start ();
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
  }

  private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;


  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      // Inflate menu resource file.
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);

      // Locate MenuItem with ShareActionProvider
      MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);

      // Fetch and store ShareActionProvider
      mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) item.getActionProvider();

      // Return true to display menu
      return true;
  }

  // Call to update the share intent
  private void setShareIntent(Intent shareIntent) {
      if (mShareActionProvider != null) {
          mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(shareIntent);
      }
  }

     @Override
     protected void onPause(){
     super.onPause();
      oursong.release();
 }

}
```

imageadapter.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    Context context;
    private int[] GalImages = new int[] {
        R.drawable.one,
        R.drawable.two,
        R.drawable.three
    };
    ImageAdapter(Context context){
        this.context=context;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
      return GalImages.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
      return view == ((ImageView) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
      ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
      int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.padding_medium);
      imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
      imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
      imageView.setImageResource(GalImages[position]);
      ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
      return imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
      ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want it to be fullscreen (be careful to the resolution of your assets), you should use a different scale type for your ImageView:

```
  imageView.setScaleType(fullscreen ? ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP : ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
```

This will crop your image, keeping the initial ratio.

[Source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)

Comment: I don't understand your question

Comment: I meant If I want only one image to appear full screen and other image according to their sizes ?

Comment: A simple `if() {} else {}` structure with either CENTER_CROP or CENTER_INSIDE

Comment: What is the image you want fullscreen?

Comment: Thank you ..I want image one.. to appear full screen

Comment: WHICH image? Sorry but if you are that new to Android, take a look at the official training guides

Comment: `imageView.setScaleType(position == 0 ? ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP : ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);`